# Converting string to int in Pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .csv with [US Congress biographical data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b_g03kXxpOPUzZeuJ3P03wGxP2JBkZuP) that I read as a Panda df:

```
df = pd.read_csv('congress100.csv', delimiter = ';', names = ['Name', 'Position', 'Party', 'State', 'Congress'], header = 0)
```

My dataframe looks like this:

```
0                   'ACKERMAN, Gary Leonard'        'Representative'    'Democrat'  'NY'  '100(1987-1988)'
1                  'ADAMS, Brockman (Brock)'               'Senator'    'Democrat'  'WA'  '100(1987-1988)'
2                   'AKAKA, Daniel Kahikina'        'Representative'    'Democrat'  'HI'  '100(1987-1988)'
3    'ALEXANDER, William Vollie (Bill), Jr.'        'Representative'    'Democrat'  'AR'  '100(1987-1988)'
4                  'ANDERSON, Glenn Malcolm'        'Representative'    'Democrat'  'CA'  '100(1987-1988)'
5                   'ANDREWS, Michael Allen'        'Representative'    'Democrat'  'TX'  '100(1987-1988)'
6                          'ANNUNZIO, Frank'        'Representative'    'Democrat'  'IL'  '100(1987-1988)'
7             'ANTHONY, Beryl Franklin, Jr.'        'Representative'    'Democrat'  'AR'  '100(1987-1988)'
8                  'APPLEGATE, Douglas Earl'        'Representative'    'Democrat'  'OH'  '100(1987-1988)'
9            'ARCHER, William Reynolds, Jr.'        'Representative'  'Republican'  'TX'  '100(1987-1988)'
10                    'ARMEY, Richard Keith'        'Representative'  'Republican'  'TX'  '100(1987-1988)'
```

I want to convert the data in the 'Congress' column to an integer. Right now, I am first converting it to a simpler string:

```
df['Congress'] = df['Congress'].str.replace(r'100\(1987-1988\)', '1987')
```

This is successful. But, I am then trying to convert that simpler string to an integer:

```
df['Congress'] = df['Congress'].pd.to_numeric(errors='ignore')
```

I am getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'pd'
```

Please help me resolve this error and simplify my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call [pd.numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[str(i + 1980) for i in range(10)], columns=['Congress'])
df['Congress'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Congress'], errors='ignore')
print(df)
```

The code above is meant as a *toy example*, you just need to change your line:

```
df['Congress'] = df['Congress'].pd.to_numeric(errors='ignore')
```

to:

```
df['Congress'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Congress'], errors='ignore')
```

Comment: This is actually replacing my entire dataframe, when I only want to change the values in the 'Congress' column.

Comment: @CharlieGoldberg are you sure? I just run it, adding a dummy column and the dummy column did not change.

Comment: When I print my new df after performing the code you suggested, I get this:    Congress
0      1980
1      1981
2      1982
3      1983
4      1984
5      1985
6      1986
7      1987
8      1988
9      1989

Comment: The code is meant as example, you need to skip the part of the creation of the dataframe. Updated the answer!

Comment: I see! I'm a novice at this. Thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score -1):

One more way to achieve it. It would work if there are only  digits in the column:-

```
 df['Congress'] = df['Congress'].astype(int)
```